# Diff between 2 data points of different dates

Tags: tableau-api

I need to find the difference between the hourly data points.

For example for the hour 13 it should be 0.03487 - 0.03355[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference between the two lines by creating a calculated field.

[red field] - [orange field]